# I'm in iptable hell

Tags: routes, debian, iptables, honeypot

So I'm relatively new to iptable routing, but what I'm trying to do should be easy.

I'm trying to direct traffic from a certain IP block, I'm using a program called inetsim and what it does is use an IP-address as the bind address and that will become similar to a router. I'm using 192.168.444.1 as my gateway and DNS server per the config instructions. There are options toward the bottom to use for routing but they have yet to be friendly. I have 2 eth ports called eth0 and eth1 the IP-addresses on them are 10.10.10.123 and 192.168.444.1 respectively. I have a reporting server on 10.10.10.250.

The machines are as follows
192.168.444.2 windows7sp1
192.168.444.1 + 10.10.10.123 debian server

The reporting server has a program that sets up a connection from the target machine to the reporting server. Under normal circumstances this would work without a hitch, however inetsim is a internet blackhole of sorts that creates iptables that route all traffic to a fakenet including unknown services, they are routed to a dummy port 1.

I need a way of forwarding the packet destined for 10.10.10.250:48002 from 192.168.444.2[connected to 192.168.444.1] through 10.10.10.123[unless there is an easier way of doing this]. I have tried snat and dnat but it seems like it mangles the packets to where they come out differently as the server rejects the packets that it gets. The windows machine states it has and established connection but like I said through packet inspection it seems to not like these packets.

The way I would like it to be done would be to not modify the actual packet at all, or at least as little as possible. If you need my rules for the iptables that I made or the rules that inetsim outputs I can post those.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you guys!

[EDIT: I have already tried a ton  of different rules, I'm not just asking because i want someone else to do it for me. I've been doing this for weeks and got it working once. Then I tried to replicate it and something broke.]

Comment: Please attach the output of `route -n` and `iptables -L`.

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.125   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.444.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

iptables -L shows nothing

http://pastebin.com/FnRF47MK are a paste or the rules that inetsim outputs from the inetsim.conf file.

Comment: Do you have [`ip forwarding` enabled](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)? What's the default policy of each of your `ip tables` chains? I also don't understand how `ip tables -L` shows nothing considering your claim that `inetsim` modifies it...

Comment: inetsim uses dnat and snat as well as mangle, it doesnt do forwarding. the default is accept but it will redirect all unknown ports to dummy port 1, if you look at the pastbin file it will show you all the rules that are entered. and forwarding is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If all the involved hosts have the Debian IP in their segment as a default route, you need no iptables at all, just activate net.ipv4.ip_forward in /etc/sysctl.conf and if you need to keep iptables activated make sure the default policy for the FORWARD table is ACCEPT.

If only the 192.168.444.2 machine has the .1 IP as route but the reporting server doesn't (you'll see connections in the reporting server queuing as SYN_RECV) you'll need a MASQUERADE target:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

I've inspected the [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/FnRF47MK), and it seems that these rules cause the trouble:

```
-A PREROUTING -j INetSim_DNAT_12257
-A POSTROUTING -j INetSim_SNAT_12257
-A INetSim_DNAT_12257 -s 192.168.444.4/32 -d 10.10.10.250/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 48002 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.444.4:48002
-A INetSim_SNAT_12257 -s 192.168.444.4/32 -d 192.168.444.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 48002 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.125
```

Can you please delete them and their associated chains and see if the problem is solved?

**EDIT:** I've noticed another rule that might be problematic. Please delete it as well and try again:

```
-A INetSim_12257 -s 192.168.444.4/32 -d 10.10.10.250/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 48002 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
```

Comment: i can delete the second two but if i delete the other ones the whole point of using this will be gone. i need this for malware analysis, hence it sending the most of the traffic to port 1, but i will get rid of the others in a second. ill give you the results in a few.

i can also get rid of the redirect rule entirely and do it from the normal iptables if you have a recommendation. ive been doing this for over a month..... :(

Comment: i got rid of them and nothing, and before i did this it was establishing a connection but the destination server(10.10.10.250) wasnt accepting the packets. :(

Comment: @user3878299, I've edited my answer with another suggestion. If that doesn't work, then taking your previous comment into account, it seems that the problem might lie in the destination server. What packet does it actually receive? Are you sure it doesn't send any reply? Please zero the packet count via `iptables -t nat -Z` and `iptables -t mangle -Z`, send the packet and view the updated count via `iptables -t nat -L -v -n` and `iptables -t mangle -L -v -n`.